# Alternative for float on moving banner

Tags: html, css, web

I'm in the process of making all my containers stay "fullsized" and positioned correctly, when the viewport is smaller than the resolution of the website.

So far everything has gone easy, except for the navbar.

On resize of window, the navbars text moves. 
It's currently held in place with float: right;

is there an alternative to float that will work in this instance? 
I tried defining left and right margins, but the text doesn't stay in a straight line.

Website in question is: njdartistics.com

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas';
    src: url(Website%20Specific%20Resources/BEBAS.TTF)
}


body {
 background-image:url(Website%20Specific%20Resources/Background.png);

 width:1920px;
 margin: auto;
}

.outercontainer{
      height:100%;
      width:100%
}

.container {
 width:960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  border-left:solid #000;
  border-right:solid #000;
background-color:#AAADAD;

}

.header {
 background-image:url(Website%20Specific%20Resources/New_Banner_.png);
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
}



A {
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family: "bebas";
 color: #fff;
 
}

li {
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
 padding-right:50px;
 margin-left:25px;
 padding-top:15px;
 font-size:24px;
 
 
}

.nav {
 float: inherit;
 position: absolute;
}
.content {
font-family: "bebas";
width: 900px;
background-color:#AAADAD;

 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

 <div class="header">
     <div class="container">
       
            
    <div class="nav">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About  Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact  Us </a></li>
        </ul>
        
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="outercontainer">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="content" >
          <p>asdasdasdasdaf</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>asdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasda</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>sdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdaf</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
       
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm understanding this, you want the navbar text responsive and to stay all on one line, correct?

To start, try changing the following css to something like this:

```
body {
background-image:url(Website%20Specific%20Resources/Background.png);
font: 100%/1.5 serif; /* 16px */
width:1920px;
margin: auto;
}

li {
list-style:none;
float:left;
font-size:1.5em;
font-size:3vw;
padding:0 1%;
width:15%;
}

.nav {
float: inherit;
position: absolute;
width:100%;
}
```

Using a combination of em and vw handles the font-size (but it should be noted that vw, or viewport width, doesn't work in every browser ([see here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)). For the browsers that don't like it, em can attempt to handle it by basing its size on whatever font size you set  for the body.

Alternatively (or, really, in addition--wrangle it as you please), you can use a media query to handle smaller viewport/screen sizes when it comes to the font-size. For example:

```
 @media (max-width: 600px) {
    body { font: 80%; }
}
```

You can size up or down based on your needs. If you set it on the body, you don't have to rewrite the li or nav css, as the em units will respond accordingly. I would avoid setting font-size in anything BUT em, as px doesn't have much flexibility.

That said, after alllll this, you really should set different breakpoints for mobile devices to, for example, stack the menu or semi-hide it with the hamburger menu icon, as the text will get very, very, very small otherwise.

Comment: This wasn't what I was after, I actually just had a look and seen what I had missed. Regardless, Thank you for teaching me a "fluid" font style.

Answer (score 0):

`header {
    background-image:url(Website%20Specific%20Resources/New_Banner_.png);
    height: 300px;
    width: 1920px;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}`

This was the issue. Width was 100% instead of a fixed resolution.